# I created a fixed navbar but now the buttons are getting on top of the navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a fixed navbar, but the problem is when I make it fixed, buttons on my page go over the navbar.

I know that when you make an element's position fixed, it goes out of the flow of the page.

But I couldn't find a working solution. I found another question about this, but the answer didn't work. The answer said that `margin-top` should be added. But it just makes the buttons go down

**Here's what I tried:**

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 13vh;
  background-color: #d6e0e4;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.contain {
  padding-top: 13vh;
}

.packing-d {
  background-color: #923a1a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: harlow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 191%;
  left: 30%;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">

    <h4>Me</h4>

  </div>
  <ul class="navlinks">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contain">
  <div>
    <img class="first-img" src="SYF1.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    <img class="second-img" src="barbeküpng.png" alt="">

    <div class="topRow" id="works">

      <button class="packing-d">Packing Designs</button>
      <button class="logo-d">Logo Designs</button>
      <button class="poster-d">Poster Works</button>
      <button class="model-d">3d Model Works</button>
      <button class="video-d">Video Animations</button>
      <button class="videoe-d">Video Edit Works</button>
      <button class="art-d">Art Works</button>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I checked your code .If you want a fixed navbar it works properly even on scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `z-index` property. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) state the following:

> The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and
> its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger
> z-index cover those with a smaller one.

So, by adding the `z-index` to the `nav` element should make the trick.

```
nav {
  ...
  z-index: 2; /* If 2 is not enough, try increasing the number. */ 
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 13vh;
  background-color: #d6e0e4;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2; /* If 2 is not enough, try increasing the number. */
}

.contain {
  padding-top: 13vh;
}

.packing-d {
  background-color: #923a1a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: harlow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 191%;
  left: 30%;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">

    <h4>Me</h4>

  </div>
  <ul class="navlinks">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contain">
  <div>
    <img class="first-img" src="SYF1.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    <img class="second-img" src="barbeküpng.png" alt="">

    <div class="topRow" id="works">

      <button class="packing-d">Packing Designs</button>
      <button class="logo-d">Logo Designs</button>
      <button class="poster-d">Poster Works</button>
      <button class="model-d">3d Model Works</button>
      <button class="video-d">Video Animations</button>
      <button class="videoe-d">Video Edit Works</button>
      <button class="art-d">Art Works</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes! didnt know there was z-indexes for elements in css. Thanks a lot this worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
nav {
...
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use sticky positioning with a top 0 value. This will work as you wanted without hacks.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 13vh;
  background-color: #d6e0e4;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.contain{
  min-height: 1500px;
}

.packing-d {
  background-color: #923a1a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: harlow;
  top: 191%;
  left: 30%;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">

    <h4>Me</h4>

  </div>
  <ul class="navlinks">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contain">
  <div>
    <img class="first-img" src="SYF1.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="about">
    <img class="second-img" src="barbeküpng.png" alt="">

    <div class="topRow" id="works">

      <button class="packing-d">Packing Designs</button>
      <button class="logo-d">Logo Designs</button>
      <button class="poster-d">Poster Works</button>
      <button class="model-d">3d Model Works</button>
      <button class="video-d">Video Animations</button>
      <button class="videoe-d">Video Edit Works</button>
      <button class="art-d">Art Works</button>

    </div>
  </div>
```